# "Show Password" in Keychain Access doesn't work

Tags: password, keychain

I am having a problem, as a program is requesting my RSA password but my Mac won't let me see it. As I check the "show password" (mostrar contraseña) chechbox, it immediately unmarks itself.

I already tried "Repair" and turning the computer off and on again (as if it ever worked) and of course, it didn't fix it.

Any suggestions?

[image: show password on keychain]

Comment: Is your keychain locked or unlocked (look at top left corner (the lock icon)

Comment: I can't see my p/w on that file either - not that I have any clue really what it's for or whether I ever gave it a p/w in the first place. I can see the p/w on `ids: identity-rsa-key-pair-signature-v1` but not on public or private key.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is unlocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the password from your keychain . You can right click on that item of which you need the password and click on "copy the password to clipboard", then you will ask to enter the login password , after that you can paste the password where you want. [image]

PFA:

Comment: I have the same symptoms as the OP, but this doesn't solve it for me. The clipboard remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Locking and unlocking the Keychain helped in my case. It's the lock icon in the upper left corner of the application's window.

[image]

Comment: Yikes! It took a couple of clicks before it would lock, but now it won't unlock (clicking on the lock does nothing), and the password I was looking for disappeared!

Comment: You can't lock and unlock the iCloud Keychain.

Answer (score -1):

I had probably the same problem, I changed my Keychain password to my login password ie. they are equal now.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609